# Check if a role has specific permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have 4 tables (`users`, `permissions`, `roles`, `roles_permissions`) with the following structure:

```
        users
_______________________
| id | name | role_id |
|____|______|_________|
| 1  | John |    1    |
|____|______|_________|


     roles
______________
| id | name  |
|____|_______|
| 1  | admin |
|____|_______|


      permissions
____________________
| id | permission  |
|____|_____________|
| 1  | view-posts  |
|____|_____________|


        roles_permissions
________________________________
| id | permission_id | role_id |
|____|_______________|_________|
| 1  |       1       |    1    |
|____|_______________|_________|
```

I want to check if the current user has specific permission like `view-posts`. This is what I tried so far in `Permission.php` model:

```
public function checkPermission($permission){ 
    $role = Auth()->user()->role_id;
    $id = $this->select('permissions.id')->join('role_permissions as rp', 'rp.permission_id', 'permissions.id')->where('rp.role_id', $role)->where('permission', $permission)->get()->toArray();
    return $id ? true : false; 
}
```

So to check with this method I can run:

```
$permission = new permission();
$check = $permission->checkPermission('view-posts');
```

Is there a short/better way?

**PS: Don't suggest using a permissions package as I want to use this custom method for a reason**

Answer (score 0):

Use relationships.

`User`:

```php
public function role() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

`Role`:

```php
public function permissions() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

Checking if user has permission, something like this:

```php
// $hasPermission will be true or false
$hasPermission = Auth::user()->role->permissions->contains('view-posts');
```

You may also want to add `role` and `role.permissions` to your user model $with property if this logic will be used inside of loops etc.

Comment: Role doesn't have one-to-many relationship with Permission. Instead, there is a table called `roles_permissions` with contains both ids

Comment: I know, that's why in my example I am using `belongsToMany`.